# Ruby's && logic behaving inconsistently when RSpec tested

Tags: ruby, rspec, boolean-expression

I have a method that includes (among subsequent lines) the following code:

```
candidate_lines.each do |line| 
  return line if priority_1?(line) && line.marked_by?(self)
end
```

The methods in it, as far as I can tell, are irrelevant. What's driving me up the wall, is I have a test that should be skipping that part of the method simply by the specification I've given:

```
it "without any priority 1 lines, returns all priority 2 lines marked by itself" do
  line1 = double :line, marked_by?: true
  line2 = double :line, marked_by?: true
  allow(joshua).to receive(:priority_1?).and_return(:false)
  expect(joshua).to receive(:candidate_lines).and_return([line1, line2])
  expect(joshua.tiebreak_lines).to eq [line1, line2]
end
```

Yet when I run the test, the return statement is getting triggered. I've tested it manually with puts statements immediately before the 'return line...' line, and it turns out that, while 'priority_1?(line)' returns false, for some reason 'priority_1?(line) && line.marked_by?(self)' is evaluating to true.

What's happening here?

Answer (score 6):

You're confusing the symbol `:false` with the boolean value `false`

Because `:false` is neither false nor nil, it is truthy, that is as far as things like `&&` or `if` are concerned, it is true.

Comment: Ah, beat me by a couple of seconds :) I was busy reformatting the code, though :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it's a shame there is such a disincentive to do that kind of thing first